# Same key binding shortcut use differently in different example.json file in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, vscode-snippets, vscode-keybinding

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+l",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "console.log('${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}$1')$2"
    }
}
```

This just wrap the text into `console.log(text);`

I need a shortcut or snippet that when I am in the `blade.json` (laravel) file

```
$fruit = mango;
```

when press ctrl+l it will insert a new line like

```
$fruit = mango;
dd($fruid);
```

And when I am in the `javscript.json` (js) file
the same shortcut (ctrl+l) or snippet will insert a new line like

```
var fruit = 'mango';
console.log(fruit);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `when` clause in the keybinding

```
"when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'json'"
```

```
"when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'javascript'"
```

don't call your JavaScript file: `javascript.json`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

But the point is I need it in a new line.

`var fruit = 'mango'; // it will remain as it is
console.log(fruit); // new  line`

Comment: @Imtiaze then add `\n\t` in your snippet